# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch data from an API and use that data in my app. But the problem is that when I try to get a certain object or data from the JSON I've just got from the API, I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined.
The property DOES exist.
By the way, I'm using React.js.
I really appreciate your help & guidance.
Here is the code:

App.js

```
{typeof weather != 'undefined' ? (
  <div>
    <div className="location-box">
      <div className="location">
        
        {weather.name},{weather.sys.country} 
      </div>
      <div className="date"> {dateBuilder(new Date())} </div>
    </div>

    <div className="weather-box">
      <div className="weather-temperature">15*C</div>
      <div className="weather">Sunny </div>
    </div>
  </div>
) : ("NULL")}
```

Api from where we are going to fetched the data.

```js
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

  const Search = (evt) => {
    if (evt.key === "Entre") {
      debugger;
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID${api.key}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())

        .then((result) => {
          setWeather(result);
          setQuery("");
          console.log(result);
        });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: That property _doesn't_ exist because when the component is initially rendered you have no data. You have an empty object. It probably is in the data, but you need to check for that _once the data is loaded_ and the state is updated.

Comment: Could you `console.log`  the `weather` variable and see if `weather.sys` actually exists?

Comment: Okay i will check the weather in console

Comment: Put this: `{weather.name},{weather.sys?.country}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain that the property does exist, then it must be the initial render. You initialise the `useStaet` with `{}` but guard against `undefined`.
So change `useState({})` to `useState()`.

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState();
```

You can also add a null check when you read `country`.

```
{weather.name}, {weather.sys?.country}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of your weather check: `typeof weather != 'undefined'` while your init value of weather is `{}`. In order to solve the problem don't set init value for weather. like this:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState();
```

So, in the first render weather value will be `undefined` and in the next render it contains your api response.